# How to convert this code in to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this email validation function in plain JavaScript:

```
function isEmail() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("email");

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        emailValue = slides.item(i).value;

        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var res = regex.test(emailValue);

        if (res == false) {

            alert("Enter valid email");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert this in to jQuery in this format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        $(".email").each(function() {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to and where you intent to use `isEmail()`?

Comment: but its not working properly in bootstap

Comment: onsubmit @ satpal

Comment: the jQuery you posted has nothing to do with the function you want to convert

Comment: perhaps you just want to trigger the function you already have. So, you don't need to convert code, but add some extra code to trigger the isEmail() function on event like click etc.

Comment: i want to  have working coding of jqury

Comment: @siddharthdarji I think you are describing the wrong problem. You keep saying the code is not working but it seems to work just fine. why would you want to re-write `isEmail` if it is not broken? ► https://jsfiddle.net/997ubvqf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $("li.email").each(function() {
            emailValue = $(this).text();
      console.log(emailValue);
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
            var res = regex.test(emailValue);

            if (res == false) {
                alert(emailValue+" email invalid");
            } else {
                alert(emailValue+" email valid");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="email">email_valid@gmail.com</li>
  <li class="email">email_valid2@gmail.com</li>
  <li class="email">email_invalid@gmailcom</li>
  <li class="email">email_valid3@gmail.com</li>
  <li class="">not email</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="button" value="validate emails"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams like the code above it trying to validate multiple emails fields on the page. So I'm going to make some dummy data on my js fiddle for you. I also optimized your code so that the variables are cached outside of the loop. If they were cached inside of the $.each loop, then it would create a new variable each time.

```
function isEmail() {

    var slides = $('.email');
    var emailValue = null;
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i
    var res = null;
    console.log(slides);

    $(slides).each(function(){

    emailValue = $(this).val();

    res = regex.test(emailValue);

    if (res==false){

        alert("Enter valid email");
        return false;
    }
    alert("Success!")
    return true;
})
```

}

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michael_coder/be3Lh3wm/1/)